# How can I use a gem/plugin to make my Rails views SEO-friendly (beyond slugs)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seo

I am trying to make my views more SEO friendly, beyond having the slugs in the URL:

- The titles are all showing up as "Untitled"
- I don't populate anything for "keyword" or meta tags
- Anything else that would help it be SEO-friendly

I'm not looking for any 'weird' or black-hat, but I know just looking at it that I'm not doing something that needs to be done in the header and stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a gem called meta-tags, which you may want to check out.

It simplifies the creation of the description and keyword metadata elements. The description and keyword metadata are two of the primary non-visible elements that will help with SEO.

[github: kpumuk/meta-tags](https://github.com/kpumuk/meta-tags)

Answer (score 5):

A bit of a broad question, but I do the following things for SEO purposes in my Rails app:

- Slugs: You already mentioned this. I've seen the screencasts on how to make a slug like my-cool-page-1, but personally I prefer the Friendly ID gem.
- Title: Title should be easy, I simply use the title field in my model or whatever serves as the title. Should you want something different in the title tag versus the title on the page (a common scenario), I would just create a new column/field for it.
- Keywords: I use the Acts as Taggable On gem, but not intially for this purpose...a project allows a person to use comma separated keywords to find related content, which is the true purpose of this gem. But I figured that the keywords would also double for meta, so I use them for that in the header, too.

EDIT:
Several ways to do this in your layouts, but helpers are the way I go. In your application.html.erb (or whatever your layout doc is), add a yield in your title tag...

```
<title><%= yield(:pagetitle) %></title>
```

Then in your app/helpers/application_helper.rb, you could declare a 'title' helper like this...

```
def title(page_title)
   content_for(:pagetitle) { page_title }
end
```

Then in your view file (like show.html.erb) for whatever model you're trying to display (let's say 'article'), you can do something like this at the top then...

```
<% title 'This is my title!' %>
```

Alternatively, you can wire it into the database's article title if using a field like that (<% title @article.title %>). Should you want a more lengthy title with site name ("This is my title | Stack Overflow"), you could do something like ("content_for(:pagetitle) { page_title + ' | Stack Overflow ' }") in that helper.

For other things like keywords and description, you can also create helpers for these and define them in your view file like above.

Comment: How do I add to the title?  That goes in the <head> but my view is after, I've seen a way in the past but don't know it...

Comment: okay, I think I get it now...I had something like this but didn't quite put it together...it was outputting the actual title in the view.  Thanks!  point awarded.

Answer (score 3):

The most important thing for SEO is indexable, relevant content with accurate metadata (url, title, etc). No plugin is going to do this for you. You just have to make sure that you use human-friendly (and therefore search-engine friendly) urls and that each page has the correct title.